Lower limit of sequence
In some propositions/lemmas such as in Fatou Lemma it appears the notion of "lower limit" of a sequence of functions, $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)$. I don't understand this notion. Does this mean a function $f$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(x) \leq f_n(x)$ but greater that any other function? Is something pointwise or in the whole interval of definition? Could somebody give me an example of sequence of functions and their lower and upper limits?

It is the function $f$ defined pointwise by the rule $f(x) = \liminf_n f_n(x)$, the latter being the $\liminf$ of a sequence of scalars
